# Regular Expression for username with particular special character

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have to validate username with special character. For example:

```
raaghu@09$%^&     
@Raaghu098          
Raaghu         
9raghu
```

Only these special characters are allowed: `%^&@#$^*:'.-_`

How can I do this?

Comment: are special characters optional? I don't get the question

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so we can further help you.

Comment: Hi AliReza,
yes special characters are optional ,if username have  any special char it should contain any of the following char 
 "%^& @#$^* " .

Comment: I tried like this 

           string username = "0sachin02$";
            var specialCharcter = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[~`!@#$%^&*'.-_]$");
            bool isMatch =  specialCharcter.IsMatch(username);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9%^&@#$^*:'.\-_]+)$`

```cs
    var pattern = @"^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9%^&@#$^*:'.\-_]+)$";
    var validUsername = "raaghu@-09_$%^&";
    var InvalidUsername = "raaghu@09$%^&!";
    
    Regex.IsMatch(validUsername , pattern); // true
    Regex.IsMatch(InvalidUsername , pattern); // false
```

Comment: Thank You ,
small update in my requirement 
pattern should also included some more char :  *'.-_
after adding new character it is not working  .

new  pattern  is 
var newpattern = (@"^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*'.-_]+)$");

Comment: I've updated the answer. you should also put your requirement in the question. good luck